# Node retornar página

Tags: node.js, promises

Tenho o seguinte bloco de codigo

```
 server.get('/energy', (req, res, next) => {
{
  const getScript = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const http = require('http'),
        https = require('https')

      let client = http

      if (url.toString().indexOf('https') === 0) {
        client = https
      }

      client.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = ''

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk
        })

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
          resolve(data)
        })
      }).on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
  };

  (async (url) => {
    console.log('Async ' + await getScript(url))
  })('http://localhost:81/energia/monitoramento/central.php?ip=147.1.3.3')
  const ret = async (url) => {
    const dados = await getScript(url)
    console.log(url)
    console.log('retorno: ' + dados)
    return dados
  }// ('http://minhaurl.com')
  console.log('Dados de retorno: ' + ret('http://minhaurl.com'))
  res.send(ret('http://minhaurl.com'))
  next()
}
```

})

Onde eu gostaria de retornar o valor que certa página traz.

Por exemplo, o trecho

```
 (async (url) => {
            console.log(await getScript(url))
          })('http://minhaurl.com')
```

No console mostra assim:

> Async
>   [129.66,30.27,3924.31,2721.89,0.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,2826.94,0.00,129.56,31.45,4075.07,-2453.22,-0.60,0.00,0.00,0.00,3253.91,0.00,128.81,29.19,3760.38,-514.79,-0.14,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,3724.98,59.76,30.60,35.10]

Nestre trecho

```
const ret = async (url) => {
        const dados = await getScript(url)
        console.log(url)
        console.log('retorno: ' + dados)
        return dados
      }
```

também volta assim:
etorno:

> [129.59,30.44,3944.05,2768.30,0.70,0.00,0.00,0.00,2809.28,0.00,129.60,31.92,4137.48,-2462.13,-0.60,0.00,0.00,0.00,3325.15,0.00,128.81,29.33,3778.27,-558.25,-0.15,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,3736.80,59.86,30.60,35.00]

Ai estou tentando mostrar esses dados na página com esse trecho

```
console.log('Dados de retorno: ' + ret('http://localhost:81/energia/monitoramento/central.php?ip=147.1.3.3'))
      res.send(ret('http://localhost:81/energia/monitoramento/central.php?ip=147.1.3.3'))
      next()
```

Mas o retorno diz assim:

> Dados de retorno: [object Promise]

E na página aparece apenas assim: `{}`

Como faço para mostrar os mesmos dados que aparecem no console na página?

> Async
>   [129.66,30.27,3924.31,2721.89,0.69,0.00,0.00,0.00,2826.94,0.00,129.56,31.45,4075.07,-2453.22,-0.60,0.00,0.00,0.00,3253.91,0.00,128.81,29.19,3760.38,-514.79,-0.14,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,3724.98,59.76,30.60,35.10]

Comment: Tente `console.log(await getScript(url).toString())`

Comment: Ele disse que não pode usar await fora de uma função async

Comment: Então a defina como assíncrona: `server.get('/energy', async (req, res, next) => {`

Comment: Continua retornando: `Dados de retorno: [object Promise]`

Comment: mude as variáveis de `const` para `let`, uma dica: expressão lambda é legal quando você quer fazer uma função de um ou duas linhas, funções grandes use `function`, deixa o código mais legível (na minha opinião)

Comment: Estou quase lá, segui sua gestão sobre o `await` mas sem o tostring no final aí retornou, porém veio entre as aspas (`"`) e dentro das as aspas no final das informações veio um `\r\n`